# Mysql question, sum some field according to multiple employee id supplied in where clause

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

I want to sum some field of database table according to the employee id supplied in where. The problem is I want to supply multiple employee ids in a single query and want the sum accordingly. Separate sum for each employee. please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT SUM(`hours`), `employee_id` FROM `timetable` WHERE `employee_id` IN (1, 3, 8, 52) GROUP BY `employee_id`;
```

Comment: Group by should be placed  after where